# Group data by year and month | django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have various reports and I want to retrieve them this way:

```
year: "2019",
months: [
   {
      month: "01",
      reports: [reports for jan]
   }
   {
      month: "02",
      reports: [reports for feb]
   }
    ]
```

I've achieved something similar on a full Django project ( see below )  but I'm unable to do the same on drf.

```
def all_reports_by_month(request):
    reports = Report.objects.all()
    total_reports = reports.count()
    ordered_reports = Report.objects \
        .annotate(month=TruncMonth('date')) \
        .values('month') \
        .annotate(c=Count('id')) \
        .values('month', 'c') \
        .order_by('-month')

    context = {
        'ordered_reports': ordered_reports,
        'total_reports': total_reports

    }
    return render(request, 'dashboard/reports.html', context)
```

this is the current setup for reports on my DRF back-end right now :

model.py :

```
class Report(models.Model):
    # each code from shop
    code =  models.ForeignKey(Shop, to_field='code' , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    clics = models.IntegerField(blank = True, null = True)
    rdv = models.IntegerField(blank = True, null = True)
    date = models.DateField(blank = True, null = True)
```

serializers.py :

```
class ReportSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Report
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py :

```
class ReportViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Report.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ReportSerializer
```

urls.py :

```
from rest_framework.routers import SimpleRouter
from .views import ReportViewSet 
router = SimpleRouter()

router.register('', ReportViewSet, basename='reports')

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

See answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've achieved this, I still don't know if its the way to go but voila. it's a good start.

```
[
    {
        "month": "2020-06-01",
        "count": 746
    },
    {
        "month": "2020-05-01",
        "count": 746
    }
]
```

The way i did it was to create a new Model called GroupReport, i added 2 fields ( Month and Count ) .

model.py :

```
class GroupReport(models.Model):
    month = models.DateField()
    count = models.IntegerField(blank = True, null = True)
```

serializer.py:

```
class ReportGroupMonthSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
        model = GroupReport
        fields = ('month','count')
```

views.py :

```
class ReportGroupData(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Report.objects.annotate(month=TruncMonth('date')).values('month').annotate(count=Count('id')).values('month', 'count').order_by('-month')
    serializer_class = ReportGroupMonthSerializer
```